# Data-dependent sections in jasper reports headers

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that needs to display a variable number of lines in a header section. Briefly, if a particular field is not empty, then I need an extra line printed. There are two "rows" in the header, each of which needs to take up 1 or 2 rows themselves. Ideally, I will not have spare white space.

I'm struggling to get my head around the "Print when", "Stretch to fit", and "Remove Line when Blank" options.

The scenarios are...

**Simple case** - 1 line per item

```
--------
Item 1 detail
--------
Item 2 detail
--------
```

**Case 2** - 2 lines for item 1, 1 line for item 2

```
--------
Item 1 detail
    extra detail for item 1
--------
Item 2 detail
--------
```

**Case 3** - 1 line for item 1, 2 lines for item 2

```
--------
Item 1 detail
--------
Item 2 detail
    extra detail for item 2
--------
```

**Case 4** - 2 lines for item 2, 2 lines for item 2

```
--------
Item 1 detail
    extra detail for item 1
--------
Item 2 detail
    extra detail for item 2
--------
```

Any pointers to examples that do this or to the relevant point in the documentation will be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to build your report header section using a subreport. Within this subreport you can have four detail bands for your lines each with its own `print when expression`.

Detailed explanation:

- Set your report header section to a minimum height that will always be reached by your subreport (e.g. one line with a row height of 10px)
- Include a subreport in this section (subreport element height is section height, it will automatically stretch with subreport growth)
- Remove unneeded sections and margins from this template
- Define four detail bands each with a specific `print when expression` and explicit height

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to avoid *more* subreports as the main report already has several but I suspect that your approach is probably the correct and *sane* approach. In the end, I solved this by creating two overlapping frames per row, with an alternate layout for each scenario. That allowed me a bit more flexibility with columns later in the row. I'll tag your response as the accepted answer and then I'll detail mine below.

Answer (score 0):

Timo gave me one (sensible) solution but I ended up using an alternate approach. I created two frames for each Item and overlaid them. One form gets printed when there is no extra information, the other gets printed when there is. That gave me the option to just add the extra information into the first few columns of output....

Version 1 - no extra information:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
|                |              |               |
| Item 1 title   | Item 1 other | Item 1 more   |
|                |              |               |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Version 2 - with extra information:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
| Item 1 title   | Item 1 other |               |
+----------------+--------------+ Item 1 more   |
|   extra detail for item 1     |               |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

The overlaid frames cover the first two columns only. It's slightly messy, but it creates the desired effect.